# C# load data from SQL Server into a DataTable and save it into SQlite

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlite

I want to load a table from my SQL Server and save it into a SQLite database by using the followingg code:

```
string connectionString = "Persist Security Info=false" +
                          ";Integrated Security=SSPI" +
                          ";Initial Catalog=tablename" +
                          ";Server=tcp:ipaddress" +
                          ";User ID=username" +
                          ";Password=password";

DataTable dt = new DataTable("ARTIKEL");

// load Data from SQL Server into DataTable
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    sqlConn.Open();

    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select ARTIKEL from ARTIKEL", sqlConn);
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

// Save DatatTable to SQlite
using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=c:\tmp\test.db"))
{
    con.Open();

    String sqlCmd = "CREATE TABLE ARTIKEL (ARTIKEL)";

    using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sqlCmd, con))
    {
        try
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    } // using

    var sqliteAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT ARTIKEL FROM ARTIKEL", con);
    var cmdBuilder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(sqliteAdapter);
    sqliteAdapter.Update(dt);
}

MessageBox.Show("fertig");
```

The data will be loaded from SQL Server (nearly 250000 rows) and the sqlite db and table (with column) will be created. But there are no row will be saved to the sqlite database.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: You created a `select` statement for your data adapter, that does not really help with [INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.insertcommand(v=vs.110).aspx)ing new records.... (hint, see the link even though that adapter is specefic to SqlServer it still applies to SqlLite)

Comment: Hi, thx. I normally know how a insert command has to looks like but in my cas i don't know how to point to the values because they comes out of the DataTable.

INSERT into ARTIKEL (ARTIKEL) values (?????)

Comment: Check out the duplicate answer. Its for SqlServer but should work the exact same for SqlLite.

Comment: In this case i have to insert the data row by row. In my main Probject i have to read many Tables from the SQL Server and save it into a SQLite Database. ATM i'm using a row by row method and i hoped to find a faster and more generic method for saving the data. thx

Comment: I think that duplicate still applies. You could probably take your filled table from sql server command and push it to your adapter with some modified code from that example. Alternatively you can try pushing the rows from one table to the other but you might have to execute a select first to populate the schema in the table from sql lite.

Comment: Hi, i found a solution:

                DataSet dsSQLITE = new DataSet();
                var sqliteAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from ARTIKEL", con);
                var cmdBuilder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(sqliteAdapter);
                sqliteAdapter.Fill(dsSQLITE);

                int index = 0;
                foreach (DataRow rw in dtSQL.Rows)
                {
                    dsSQLITE.Tables[0].ImportRow(rw);
                    dsSQLITE.Tables[0].Rows[index].SetAdded();
                    index++;
                }